# Inaccessible method on TS object

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am attempting to make use of a method that is stored on a Typescript class from within a Vue component.

When attempting to use a method defined on said class from another class (which just so happens to be a Typescript Vue component), an Uncaught TypeError is returned to the console saying that the method I am trying to make use of is not a function

Consider the following Paper class:

```js
export class Paper {
    paperSize: number;
    documentTitle: string;

    constructor() {
        paperSize = 1;
        documentTitle = "Arbitrary title";
    }

    getDocumentRatio(): number {
        return ArbitraryLibrary.arbitraryNumericFunction(this.paperSize);
    }
}
```

When trying to use this class (the Vue component) in another class like:

```js
@Component()
export class PaperUser {
    paper = new Paper();
    paperUserMethod() {
        ...
        const unimportant = this.paper.getDocumentRatio();
        ...
    }
    ...
    // Wherever the method gets used
        this.paperUserMethod();
    ...
}
```

Execution of the method is then interrupted, because using the function in this manner creates the TypeError

Initially thinking that this might be a binding issue I attempted something more like

```js
...
this.paper.getDocumentRatio().bind(this.paper);
...
```

but evidently this does not work because binding in this way would be as effective as method chaining - with the IDE (VSCode) asserting that property 'bind' does not exist on type 'number'.

Comment: Hi, let's start with: which method are we talking about *(as in which method is missing)*? And what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first hand, you have to set your attribut in your constructor with `this.myAttribut` and on second hand you are using your method out of a method implementation of you class, you can try this :

```
class Paper {
    paperSize: number;
    documentTitle: string;
    constructor() {
        this.paperSize = 1;
        this.documentTitle = "Arbitrary title";
    }
    getDocumentRatio(): number {
        // try to be trivial on first attempt
        return this.paperSize;
    }
}

class PaperUser {
    paper = new Paper();
    paperUserMethod() {
        return this.paper.getDocumentRatio();
    }
    usePaperuser(){
        this.paperUserMethod();
    }
}
```